# Best method to combine 2 images with points of reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 PNG images (image A and image B), each one with 2 points (point L and point R) which I know its pixel coordinates. Both images are placed inside a .

I need to make a javascript or jQuery function to combine these images. The image A should remain static, and the image B should be moved and change size in order to combine the points, L with L and R with R.

Like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/5fq3qb.jpg

Whats the best method to achieve this?

So far I can only move the images to combine both points L, and resize image B, how can I find the angle to rotate it and combine point R?

Comment: I offer this solution: math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward solution:

1. Calculate the angle you need to rotate the image: "current angle between points on pink image" - "angle between points on a blue image" (to more clear - angle between horizontal line and line that goes through both points)
2. Calculate the scale: distance between points on blue / distance between points on pink

Then apply both transformations

References:

- To calculate angle use http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/vec/angle_vectors.html (or use google with "angle 2 vectors" request)

Comment: You also need to apply a translate transformation to the second image.

Comment: @Brian Gordon: that's what OP already mentioned so I omitted as obvious